# function using mysqli_fetch_array to output database records

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm still learning about functions, and am a bit unsure.

I have this code here:

```
<?php
include ('blah.html');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Connected to mysql and the testing database</p>";
}

/*function produceTable(){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT studentid, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) as name,phone, email, courseid FROM students WHERE courseid > 1500 ORDER BY lastname");
    return $result;
}*/
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT studentid, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) as name,phone, email, courseid FROM students WHERE courseid > 1500 ORDER BY lastname");
$numRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align = 'center'>".$row['studentid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['courseid']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<p>".$numRecords." records found with course id larger than 1500</p>";                    
?>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I've commented out the function. If you ignore the function this code works and outputs the records I want, but I need to be able to make it work with a function. The function needs to be called produceTable() and accept one parameter called $result. It also needs to use the mysqli_fetch_array() to ouput the records.

Comment: just feed the connection object on the function, then just finally `return` the fetched results after the loop

Comment: Your function is ok but the variable $conn is not in scope. You must pass $conn as a parameter.  `function produceTable($conn) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `produceTable()` `$conn` is `undefined`. Just pass `$conn` as parameter. like this

```
function produceTable($conn){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT studentid, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) as name,phone, email, courseid FROM students WHERE courseid > 1500 ORDER BY lastname");
    return $result;
}

$result = produceTable($conn);
$numRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused on how to put it all together. I keep getting undeclared variable errors (for $result or $numRecords).

Comment: @user2358021 call the `produceTable()` and assign to `$result` as I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Is your function next:

```
function produceTable(){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ...");
    return $result;
}
```

?

`$conn` has no value. isn't it? Try to pass this param to the function

Comment: please use comment section instead ... if you have any question regarding question

Comment: @NullPoiиteя 5 minutes ago I had no enough reputation for comments. And right question can contain an answer, isn't it?

Comment: yes question can  contain an answer .....                but i am telling your answer is more fitted to comment section rather than answer since you are asking question in answer section